# angular js: UI Grid set onclick event row and identify clicked row

Tags: angularjs

```
   $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:9080/ProdMakerDev/pm/managejobs/search/"+val
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
        }); 
    }
    $scope.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: [
                         { name:'Status', field: 'Status', width: "65", cellTemplate:"<div class={{row.entity.Status}}></div>"},
                         { name:'', field:'edit/delete/startnow' , width: "70", 
                             cellTemplate:" <img src='Images/edit.gif' /> <img src='Images/delete.gif' /> <img src='Images/startnow.gif' />"   },
                         { name:'Jobname', field: 'Jobname', width: "297"},
                         ]
    };
```

[image]
in above screenshot. on click of edit button edit the name & delete vice versa.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below code if you want to attach any event to row elements.

ng-click="grid.appScope.<>(row, $event)"

For e.g:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: [
                         { name:'Status', field: 'Status', width: "65", cellTemplate:"<div class={{row.entity.Status}}></div>"},
                         { name:'', field:'edit/delete/startnow' , width: "70", 
                             cellTemplate:' <img ng-click="grid.appScope.edit(row, $event)" src='Images/edit.gif' /> <img src='Images/delete.gif' ng-click="grid.appScope.delete(row, $event)" /> <img src='Images/startnow.gif' ng-click="grid.appScope.startNow(row, $event)"  />'   },
                         { name:'Jobname', field: 'Jobname', width: "297"},
                         ]
    };
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.edit = function(row, $event) {
  var element = $event.currnetTarget;
  var rowObj = row.entity[your-data-object];
}
```